# How to increment project version in Cordova from a Grunt task?

Tags: cordova, gruntjs, version

Ok, first off, my NodeJS and Grunt Fu is perhaps lacking, so please forgive me if there is an "obvious and easy" answer.

So basically I'm using Grunt, Yeoman with AngularJS Generator, and Cordova.

The basic built is setup and working nicely, meaning I can run `grunt build`, and have the results slurped into the cordova build (by using the the still not documented `--link-to` feature of cordova CLI).

Well and good.
NOW what I'm trying to do is add a grunt task that will increment the project version, AND have that pull through into the `config.xml` on the cordova side (from where it does pull through into the platform builds - at least with Android).

So I've found [grunt-bump](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bump), and managed to get that working without problems.

Now I need to somehow take the updated version number (after `grunt bump` did it's thing), and get that injected into the Cordova `config.xml`.

I've looked at [grunt-cordova-config](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cordova-config), which might work, but the task seems to be currently broken. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/grunt-cordova-config/issues/1) on github about it.

So...anybody have some thoughts on how do this?

Or is there a completely different approach (I like that `bump` does the whole committing, tagging and pushing thing though...)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since nobody seems to be willing to bite, here is how I got it working.

First, setup your project as (vaguely) described above, using yeoman angularJS generator, and cordova with the --link-to option.

Secondly add and configure [grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump) to your project.

Then add a section to the [copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) task (which I hope is present, if not follow the link and add it)

```
cordovaConfig: {
            src: 'app/config.cordova.xml',
            dest: '../cordova/config.xml',                  
            options: {
                process: function (content, srcpath) {  
                    /*
                    * Ok, I will be the first to admit that this is HORRIBLY inefficient,
                    * BUT it works. Which is more than I can say for other approaches I tried.
                    */
                    var locPkg = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
                    grunt.log.write ('new version ' +locPkg.version );
                    var deVersion = 'version="' + locPkg.version + '"';
                    return content.replace(/version="\d+\.\d+\.\d+"/,deVersion);
                }
            }
        }
```

For extra great power, register a new grunt task:

```
 grunt.registerTask('release', [
    'bump',
    'copy:cordovaConfig'
  ]);
```

And then you can run `grunt release`, and have upgraded versions in all the correct places ;)

Comment: Side note: a better way of handling the replacement, would be to first check for a regex match, and THEN do the text replacement part.

Comment: And another thing: just found out, if `bump` is configured to update a global configuration component (for example with `updateConfigs: ['pkg']`), you can access this value with `grunt.config.get('pkg.version')`. This assume you loaded package.json with `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')` int the top level of `grunt.initConfig`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I had the same issue and created a powershell script although i'm using it for a cordova build it could be adapted to work so it would take version 1.1.1.2 and increment it to 1.1.2.2 and kick off the build.

```
   #Get Current Version
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content C:\YOURAPP\config.xml
$myXML.widget.version
$oldVersion = $myXML.widget.version
$splitVersion = $oldVersion.Split(".")
#Set Current Version to increment by 1
$newVersion = ([int]$splitVersion.Item(2) + 1)
$oldVersion = $oldVersion.Remove(4,1)
$oldVersion = $oldVersion.Insert(4,$newVersion)
#Set new value
$myXML.widget.version = $oldVersion
#Save changes
$myXML.Save("C:\YOURAPP\config.xml")
#Go to cordova folder
cd C:\YOURAPP
#Build App
cordova build android
```

Hope this helps someone :)